# Producer Kafka throws deserialization exception

Tags: spring, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have one topic and Producer/Consumer:

**Dependencies (Spring Initializr)**

- Producer (apache kafka)
- Consumer (apache kafka stream, cloud stream)

**Producer:**

KafkaProducerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Person> kafkaTemplate(){
      return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Person> producerFactory(){
      Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
      configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
      configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
      configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

      return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class KafkaProducerApplication {

    private KafkaTemplate<String, Person> kafkaTemplate;

    public KafkaProducerApplication(KafkaTemplate<String, Person> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public Mono<List<Person>> findAll(){
        var personList = Mono.just(Arrays.asList(new Person("Name1", 15),
                    new Person("Name2", 10)));

        personList.subscribe(dataList -> kafkaTemplate.send("topic_test_spring", dataList.get(0)));

        return personList;
    }

}
```

It works correctly when accessing the endpoint and does not throw any exception in the IntelliJ console.

**Consumer:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: personService
      bindings:
        personService-in-0:
          destination: topic_test_spring
      kafka:
        bindings:
          personService-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value:
                  deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      binders:
        brokers:
          - localhost:9091
          - localhost:9092
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: "*"
```

PersonKafkaConsumer

```
@Configuration
public class PersonKafkaConsumer {

  @Bean
  public Consumer<KStream<String, Person>> personService(){
    return kstream -> kstream.foreach((key, person) -> {
      System.out.println(person.getName());
    });

  }

}
```

Here I get the exception when run the project.

> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.example.producer.model.Person' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.nttdata.bootcamp.yanki.model, com.nttdata.bootcamp.yanki.model.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*). org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.

The package indicated in the exception refers to the entity's package but in the producer. The producer's properties file has no configuration.